# Facebook API catch wrong image

Tags: html, facebook, api

Open graph properties - correct, but in the share window i see image which not specified in the og properties;

Here is an example image

[image]

Please tell me, why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bigger image: [minimum size is 200×200](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images).

Comment: you mean this: the image size is not suitable for facebook share window?

Answer (score 0):

After using [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) check the `Warning That Should Be Fixed` section

[image]

Follow the [Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) for showing your images in your website or mobile apps

I would recommend `600 x 315`